# Is it okay for a non-cryptographer to submit crypto code to an open source probject?

Tags: implementation

I am not a cryptographer, nor do I claim to be.

However, at times I have wanted to contribute to open source cryptography projects such as libsodium.  The maintainer of libsodium is a cryptographer, and I consider it a good assumption that they will review any code submitted to the repo.

Under these conditions, is it okay to write the code, doing my best to get things right, and rely on a qualified person to catch any mistakes?

Edit: I am talking about implementations of already well-known, software-friendly algorithms that are not especially complex.  That is: zero new ideas, just "grunt work" — the problem is already solved and there is only the relatively mechanical task of writing the code.

I am *especially* talking about "glue code" that ties existing primitives together.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic here.....In any case, the issue is not whether it is ok or not. The problem is that there are many things that a good crypto implementation has to consider that the most probable result is code that is not going to be accepted in a reputable project.

Comment: I agree that this is most likely off topic. This is more of a general software engineering question.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to ask this question on the libsodium mail list than here. After all it really comes down to the policies of that particular project.

Comment: Many projects lack even the basic unit testing, e.g testing the boundaries of input parameters. You can always contribute by *adding* tests or documentation. Actual code indeed should be thoroughly reviewed *before* it is added in the "trunk" (or release branch). The chances are too high that it escapes attention otherwise. Anyway, that's my *opinion*. By testing software you learn a lot about the code and the processes around it by the way and you learn to be critical; a lot of companies will first put somebody in the test department before moving them on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least make sure that your code is reviewed. Verify you don't have possible buffer overflow or any kinds of implementation attack because of the use of non secure primitives. Moreover if you do so, **test all your functions** and in particular :

- bitwise rotations
- permutations
- S-boxes...

Check everything as it is really easy to screw with it. Then use the test vector provided by the algorithm and check your results. For example [here](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/bc/des/Des-64-64.test-vectors) are the test vector I used when I implemented DES (which I don't use in production).

You can find other tests vectors of most ciphers [here](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/), i.e. for the [AES-128-128](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/bc/rijndael/Rijndael-128-128.unverified.test-vectors).